# How to pass variable arguments from bash script to python script

Tags: python, bash, parameters, arguments

I've been trying to solve this issue for sometime now with no luck. The crust of the situation is that I'm using a bash script to send parameters to a a python script:

Example:

foo.sh calls bar.py....the call looks like: bar.py $var1 $var2 ... $varn

The python script then prints all the arguments using the sys.argv array. The python script works correctly from the command line, but when called from with the bash script (i.e foo.sh), I get no output from bar.py.

Also, I started foo.sh with the "#!/bin/bash -x" option and watched the output as well.

TO summarize:

- Two scripts, foo.sh and bar.py
- foo.sh calls bar.py, passing variables of foo.sh as arguments to bar.py
- bar.py prints the arguments it sees using sys.argv
- bar.py works when run from its own terminal, doesn't work when called from foo.sh

Any help would be awesome!!!!

Thanks!

Edit: Hi all, thanks for the replies, the complete code is pretty long...but... the contents of the two scripts could be summed

foo.sh ***_*__*_***

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a list1;  
declare -a list2;  

list1=("foo" "bar" "please");  
list2=("foo" "bar" "please" "help");  

declare -a joined;  

joined=( $(bar.py "${list1[@]}" "${list2[@]}" ) );
```

bar.py ***_*__*_***

```
#!/bin/python
import sys  

for arg in sys.argv:  
    print arg
```

As I assume all the indents in the python are correct (not sure how StackOverflow does this yet :) ). These two represent the core of the issue i'm having. As stated, bar.py prints arguments correctly, when it it not called from foo.sh.

PS: I did mean to say "crust"

Comment: please post the actual bash script, it'd make it much easier to see whatts wrong

Comment: Then you're doing something very wrong. Post minimal code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Can the python script print anything when called from the bash script?  E.G. if you add `print "wtf"` at the top of `foo.py`, do you see that output when you run the bash script?

Comment: Also: I think you mean the "crux" of the situation LOL

Comment: @tobyodavies and Ignacio, I posted the contents

Comment: @intuited, Yes the python script can print whatever I want, including arguments passed from the commandline .... and I did mean to say "crust" lol

Comment: @certifiedNoob Your code captures the output of `bar.py` to the `joined` variable. I updated my post to demonstrate.

Comment: @birryree, that is exactly how my code appears in the script I wrote...save the values in the two arrays don't contain double quotes....not sure if that has any bearing on the issue...

Comment: @certifiedNoob putting in double quotes should not affect it (I tested it in my environment as well).

Comment: @birryree, does it matter that some of the array elements have "./" as in "./filename"? I notice two different behaviors:

bar.py p1 p2  
>p1  
>p2  

bar.py ./p1 ./p2  
> ./bar.py
> ./p1
> ./p2

Any ideas?

Comment: @certifiedNoob if you mean my `./pytest.py` argument, I'm trying to run that script. If you mean the array strings in `list1` and `list2`, then those `./` are interpreted as part of the command line arguments to the python script.

Comment: @birryee, no I was referring to the parameters only...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit, since code has been posted**

Your code is doing the correct thing - except that the output from your `bar.py` script is being captured into the array `joined`. Since it looks like you're not printing out the contents of `joined`, you never see any output.

Here's a demonstration:

File `pybash.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a list1
declare -a list2

list1=("Hello" "there" "honey")
list2=("More" "strings" "here")

declare -a joined

joined=($(./pytest.py ${list1[@]} ${list2[@]}))
echo ${joined[@]}
```

File `pytest.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for i in sys.argv:
    print "hi"
```

This will print out a bunch of 'hi' strings if you run the bash script.

Comment: @birryee, Yes the script has +x permissions...not sure what the first question is asking...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I figured it out, I had some weired combo of characters, the line was not properly escaped. I changed it from

> var=( $( some commands) )

to

> var=( some commands ) // using backticks (still learning the SO editor...)

Bash escaping is some ride lol! To those who answered, thanks for all your help

Answer (score -2):

I have pretty much the exact setup that you are describing, and this is how my bash script looks:

```
VAR1=...
VAR2=...
VAR3=...

python my_script.py $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3
```